# ClosedRange second parameter to be smaller and return nil

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create an extension to the `ClosedRange` type, that would return `nil` if the second parameter is lower than the first parameter.

I'm thinking to make something that could be used like this: `myClosedRange = ClosedRange.safe(4,3)`

I've created an extension like this:

```
extension ClosedRange {
    static func safe(_ lhs: Int, _ rhs: Int) -> ClosedRange<Int>? {
        guard lhs >= 0, rhs >= lhs else {
            return nil
        }
        return lhs ... rhs
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it like this: `let myRange = ClosedRange.safe(4, 3)`, I'm getting the error: `Generic parameter 'Bound' could not be inferred`

I don't understand the error and don't know how to fix it? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the generic type

```
let myRange = ClosedRange<Int>.safe(4, 3)
```

or constrain the Range accordingly

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound : Comparable, Bound : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    static func safe(_ lhs: Bound, _ rhs: Bound) -> ClosedRange<Bound>? {
        guard lhs >= 0, rhs >= lhs else {
            return nil
        }
        return lhs ... rhs
    }
}
```

Comment: Ironically, `let myRange = ClosedRange<String>.safe(4, 3)` would also work...

Comment: You suggested to add more generic constraints. 

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to mention that *some* generic type has to be specified in the first solution, but it does not matter which one.

Comment: *Inferring* the type (as in the second solution) is certainly better.

Comment: It works great using Swift 5.1, answer accepted. For older versions it might be `let range1: ClosedRange<Int>? = ClosedRange.safe(2, 4)` or `let range2 = ClosedRange.safe(2, 4) as ClosedRange<Int>?` .